# Convert arguments to types expected by wrapped function

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates

Let's say that I want that I have a generic function `F` taking arguments of types `Args` and returning `R`. I want to wrap this function so that it fits the form:

```
using gen_type = void (*)(struct value *values,
                          size_t num_args,
                          struct value *return_value)
```

I also have functions converting to and from a generic `struct value`:

```
template<T> T from_value(struct value);
// or have something like from_value_(struct value, int&)
// called from from_value
template<> from_value<int>(struct value);
struct value to_value(int i);
```

Now, can I have a function like:

```
template<typename F, typename ... Args>
gen_type wrap(F func) {
    return [](struct value *values,
              size_t num_args,
              struct value *return_value) {
        if (num_args != sizeof...(Args)) { /* error */ }
        auto res = func(/* apply from_value<> to each argument type */)
        *return_value = to_value(res);
    }
}
```

The question is what should go on where the comment is.

(Side question: is there any way to avoid having to describe the argument types of F when invoking `wrap`?)

Comment: Is it ok for you to use external libraries? If yes then there are a few ways how it could be done with help of [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hana/).

Comment: Why are you mixing C style struct with modern C++?

Comment: Ain't gonna fly. Your lambda needs to capture `func`, but a lambda with captures is not convertible to a plain function pointer. `gen_type` is not large enough to store an arbitrary callable object in.

Comment: As to how to call `func`; this can be done pretty easily via a helper function and [`std::make_index_sequence`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)

Comment: Re: avoid describing types of `F`. Not in general, since a callable object may have multiple overloads of `operator()`, or `operator()` may be a function template. Yes, if you limit yourself to plain function pointers, and/or classes with exactly one non-template `operator()`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnick you're right. See also my comments on the answer below. I need the result castable to a function pointer. It's not needed that the function wrap a function known only at runtime (like a function pointer); the template can be a provided a known function or equivalent at compile time.

Comment: @EvgenyS. yes I'd prefer that to a c++17/20 solution

Comment: I think it is doable if `F` is a pointer to a function, not a generic callable. If you're OK with it I would try to implement it as an answer.

Comment: The technique that could help is passing pointer to a function as a non-type template parameter to a function.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why do you want to convert functions to the similar format? Isn't there a simpler solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example how it could be done using [Boost.Hana](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/hana) with `func` as a template argument.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana=boost::hana;

// sample value type
struct value
{
    size_t content;
};

// sample conversion functions for sample value type

template <typename T>
T from_value(const value& val)
{
    return T(val.content);
}
template <>
int from_value<int>(const value& val)
{
    return val.content*2;
}
template <>
float from_value<float>(const value& val)
{
    return val.content*3.0;
}

template <typename T>
value to_value(const T& val)
{
    return value{static_cast<size_t>(round(val))};
}

// concatenate results of from_value to tuple

template <typename ...>
struct concat_values
{
};

template <typename T>
struct concat_values<T>
{
    template <typename ArrT>
    static auto apply(size_t index,const ArrT& arr)
    {
        return hana::make_tuple(from_value<T>(arr[index]));
    }
};

template <typename T, typename ... Types>
struct concat_values<T,Types...>
{
    template <typename ArrT>
    static auto apply(size_t index,const ArrT& arr)
    {
        return hana::prepend(concat_values<Types...>::apply(index+1,arr),
                            from_value<T>(arr[index])
                            );
    }
};

// wrap lambda
template <typename FuncT, FuncT func, typename ... Args>
auto wrap()
{
    return [](value *values,
            size_t num_args,
            value *return_value)
    {
        if (num_args != sizeof...(Args)) { throw std::runtime_error("Invalid number of arguments!"); }

        auto res=hana::unpack(
            concat_values<Args...>::apply(0,values),
            *func
        );
        *return_value = to_value(res);
    };
}

// try it

// sample func
double sample_sum(size_t a, int b, float c)
{
    return a+b*2+c*3;
}

// sample function with C-style signature that accepts wrapped function
void sample_invoke(void (*f)(value*,size_t,value*))
{
    value inputs[3]={{1},{2},{3}};
    value result{0};
    (*f)(inputs,3,&result);

    std::cout<<"Result "<<result.content<<std::endl;
}

// run
int main()
{
    auto wrapped=wrap<decltype(&sample_sum),&sample_sum,size_t,int,float>();
    sample_invoke(wrapped);
    return 0;
}
```

Prints:

```
Result 36
```

See [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ebccdd3a38ee337).

**UPDATE**

Another implementation with `std::index_sequence`:

```cpp
// apply function
template <typename ... Args, typename FuncT, std::size_t... Idx>
auto apply_func(FuncT func,value* values,std::index_sequence<Idx...>)
{
    return func(from_value<Args>(values[Idx])...);
}    

// wrap lambda
template <typename FuncT, FuncT func, typename ... Args>
auto wrap()
{
    return [](value *values,
            size_t num_args,
            value *return_value)
    {
        if (num_args != sizeof...(Args)) { throw std::runtime_error("Invalid number of arguments!"); }

        auto res=apply_func<Args...>(*func,values,std::index_sequence_for<Args...>());
        *return_value = to_value(res);
    };
}
```

Live [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b22679253834c1d5).

Comment: Thanks this put me on the right track, though I ended up using `std::tuple` instead of `hana::tuple` and `std::index_sequence` like Jarod42 suggested (instead of recursion).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is was you want, but [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any) (C++17) seems to fit your requirements:

```
template <typename Sig> struct callable_trait;

// Miss all combinations of cv qualifier, ref qualifier, C-ellipsis
template <typename R, typename C, typename ... Args>
struct callable_trait<R (C::*)(Args...) const>
{
    using Ret = R;
    using ArgsTuple = std::tuple<Args...>;
};

// assume no overloads, and const non template operator from above minimal specialization
template <typename C> struct callable_trait : callable_trait<decltype(&C::operator())> {};


template <typename F>
auto wrap(F func) {
    return [=](const std::any values[], std::size_t num_args, /* std::span<std::any> */
              std::any* return_value) {
        using ArgsTuple = typename callable_trait<F>::ArgsTuple;
        constexpr std::size_t size = std::tuple_size_v<ArgsTuple>;
        if (num_args != size) { throw std::runtime_error("wrong number of arguments");/* error */ }
        // C++20 construct actually, you might create free function instead prior that
        *return_value = [=]<std::size_t...Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>){
            return func(std::any_cast<std::tuple_element_t<Is, ArgsTuple>>(values[Is])...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<size>()); // immediate call
    };
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b9c1f2f1c9db924)

Comment: Thanks, but I understand correctly, as @IgorTandetnik mentioned, the return value cannot be converted to a function pointer (which is need because the ultimate objective is to wrap C++ functions to expose them to a C library). `func` can be known at compile time, so I guess this is in principle possible, but I guess the function must be given as a template parameter, not as an argument.

Comment: Indeed, as `func` is captured, it is not convertible to function pointer, passing it by template solve the issue: [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/913c724373ee77cc). As it is for C, `std::any` is not the way to go, so need other change too.